# ggplot2/knitr: geom_col shows breaks in PDF but not in RStudio/HTML

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

When including a plot with `geom_col` in an R Markdown report knitted to *pdf*, the stacked breaks between observations are made visible as gray lines:

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = midwest) +
  geom_col(mapping = aes(x = state, y = poptotal))
```
````

[image]

But when I run the exact same code directly in R Studio (or knit to HTML), the columns are shown as solid:

[image]

Is there something special to do to make the different observations not be shown in a pdf (e.g., to make the pdf-knitted plot look like the HTML-knitted one)?

Comment: what happens if you set `colour = NA` in `geom_col`? Alternatively calculate the sum before using ggplot

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it helped fixing your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you Try using `geom_bar()` instead of `geom_col()`, because `geom_col()` was created afterwards, its basically `geom_bar()` only

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = midwest) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",mapping = aes(x = state, y = poptotal))
```
````

It might work, try it and let me know
You can also set `fill` and check what happens

```
geom_bar(stat="identity",mapping = aes(x = state, y = poptotal,fill="gray60"))
```

Comment: EDIT: No, using a `geom_bar()` with `stat="identity"` has the same result. I could try and force the color/fill to be the same, but I was hoping there was a reason the same rendered plot image (png) would appear differently depending on the target medium.

Comment: Can you show the pdf save code. I'm not sure what function you use to save it as pdf....or is it just the export in the 'RStudio'.
I tried saving it into pdf from the Export option and it worked fine for me. I think there is probably Version error with your 'R' or 'RStudio'. Try updating it if you're running an outdated version.

Comment: I'm just using the "Knit" button in RStudio. I'm using the latest RStudio, R 3.4.4, and Pandoc 1.19.2.1.

Comment: Is the same problem occuring if you add coord_flip() to the plot?

Comment: Same behavior: can see the row divisions when knit to pdf, but not when knit to HTML.